# How to hide or encrypt contents of jar containing in Install4J

Tags: install4j

I used install4J and created an exe out of jar file. But here the issue is, the jar files needs to be in the installation directory, otherwise the exe wont work if I share that exe to outside world.

Is there a way to encrypt or hide contents of jar file in Install4j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install4j does not offer features to encrypt or hide JAR files. These strategies aslo make limited sense because you have to pass the unencrypted JAR files to the JVM at some point and then it's quite easy to extract them.

Use an obfuscator like proguard instead.